# Issue accessing elements of nested associative array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

So I have some data that's coming back from a database query, and the resulting array (gotten with print_r) looks like this (it's assigned to a var called $locationData):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [location_name] => Cook Minnesota
            [location_lat] => 47.72037
            [location_long] => -90.32667
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [location_name] => Lake Minnesota
            [location_lat] => 47.18238
            [location_long] => -91.35301
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [location_name] => St. Louis Minnesota
            [location_lat] => 46.83572
            [location_long] => -91.96299
        )
 )
```

I have a foreach loop that needs to grab the location_name from each. It looks like this:

```
foreach ($locationData as $location => $value ) {
   echo '<p>name ' . $location['location_name']. '</p>';
}
```

I'm 99% certain this should work; it's basically the same code I've used a dozen times before. But the echo is not returning anything - not even the static text (`<p>name`). It's not throwing any errors, and if I try to do a print_r($location), I get nothing.

Any ideas? I'm sure it's something really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `$value['location_name']` because `$value` represents the arrays while `$location` represents the indexes of the arrays:

```
   echo '<p>name ' . $value['location_name']. '</p>';
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try that and it seemed not to work, but it turns out the actual issue has nothing to do with the PHP - I'm populating a javascript array variable with the php loop, and I put the echo statement inside the var's array tag, which means I couldn't see the values until I did a view-source.

Comment: @mailo: No, EmmyS's answer to our comment is "good" one :) Now I am literally lost.

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
foreach ($locationData as $location => $value ) {
   echo '<p>name ' . $value['location_name']. '</p>';
}
```